# How to get column by "name string" from Range type

Tags: c#, string, excel

For example i have in excel file:

```
colname1 colname2 colname3
1 2 3
4 2 4
5 6 4
6 1 2
```

This is part of my code :

```
 public IList<Range> GetColVal(string _path)
    {


        IList<Range> rowList= new List<Range>();
        System.Data.DataTable tableExcel = new System.Data.DataTable();

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(_path);     
        app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        wb = app.Workbooks.Open(_path, Type.Missing);
        sheet = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];
        Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;
        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        Range tmpVar;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            tmpVar = sheet.Rows[i];
            rowList.Add(tmpVar);

        }
        return rowList;
    }
```

I'd like to get field by column name from each row while iterate it by foreach

eg.

```
foreach(var a in ListRows)
{
a["colname1"] ...
}
```

How to contain col name in each row ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
{
    string conStr = "";
    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}";
            break;
    }

    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

    //Get the name of First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

an use it like this

```
DataTable dt = ExcelToDataTable(@"C:\Users\Nikhil\Desktop\1.xls", ".xls", "true");
```

Then you can loop over the DataTable with Column Names.